# Getting value from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

while writing Dijkstra function for finding the shortest path in a directed graph I've met a problem. An error occured which is: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'AtlasView' and 'int'`
Here I pass the code lines where the error bangs:

```
for childNode, weight in graph[minNode].items():
    if weight + shortest_distance[minNode] < shortest_distance[childNode]:
```

and the graph representation looks like this:

[image: Graph representation]

Comment: Please post the complete error and loop

Comment: You may want to provide us with [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: So the whole loop is: 
for childNode, weight in graph[minNode].items():
            if weight + shortest_distance[minNode] < shortest_distance[childNode]:
                shortest_distance[childNode] = weight + shortest_distance[minNode]
                previous_one[childNode] = minNode
and the whole error is:  if weight + shortest_distance[minNode] < shortest_distance[childNode]:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'AtlasView' and 'int'

Comment: Please edit the question to add the full error message.  To find your problem, I recommend adding a command to print `weight` right before the line where it gets the error.  I think you'll find `weight` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have to convert both vars to the same type when adding, so this should look like this:

```
float(weight) + float(shortest_distance[minNode])
```

Comment: By doing so I reveive an error:float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AtlasView' when it comes to "weight"

Comment: It's because you have object of type 'AtlasView'. Python (and I) don't know what is it or how to convert it to number or how to add it to another value.